# Blank screen when accessing Sagepay

Tags: wordpress, opayo

Using this wordpress plugin

http://www.woothemes.com/products/sage-pay-form/

We have been for a couple of months and everything runs fine, but today when a transaction goes to the sagepay page all that is there is a blank page.

There hasn't been any changes to the site recently to make this happen.

Example:
https://live.sagepay.com/gateway/service/cardselection?vpstxid={7C5EAC6A-D8DE-9EFB-9CAB-8356D67F9ED3}

Is this a server problem on sagepays side?

Comment: That link doesn't turn up blank for me...

Comment: The link will always be an error so long after the transaction. If on the original transaction registration a blank page displayed, it kind of makes me think that there may be an issue with the payment page template being displayed. Have you tried switching to the Sage Pay 'Default' template and seeing what happens?

Comment: I switched back to using an earler protocol in the settings and that works, but that's supported until July 15th , so I will have to find a solution before then.